# Example of Where cluase query including the MSACCESS database connection in C#

Tags: c#, where-clause, oledbconnection

similar to title.
just want an example of Oledb connection with Where clause query.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Function SendQueryToOLE() As DataSet
    Dim rdrDataReader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
    Dim cmdCommand As OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim dtsData As New DataSet
    Dim dtbTable As New DataTable
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim SQLStatement As String
    Dim oleConnection As OleDb.OleDbConnection

        oleConnection.ConnectionString = YourConnectionString

        SQLStatement = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Field=1"

        oleConnection.Open()

        cmdCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(SQLStatement, moleConnection)

        rdrDataReader = cmdCommand.ExecuteReader()

        For i = 0 To (rdrDataReader.FieldCount - 1)
            dtbTable.Columns.Add(rdrDataReader.GetName(i), rdrDataReader.GetFieldType(i))
        Next
        dtbTable.BeginLoadData()

        Dim values(rdrDataReader.FieldCount - 1) As Object

        While rdrDataReader.Read
            rdrDataReader.GetValues(values)
            dtbTable.LoadDataRow(values, True)
        End While
        dtbTable.EndLoadData()

        dtsData.Tables.Add(dtbTable)

        moleConnection.Close()

        Return dtsData

End Function
```